# Inverse of an AR(1) or Laplacian (?) or Kac-Murdock-Szegö matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-inverse, toeplitz-operators

My current problem involves having an exact (symbolic) inverse of a scaled AR(1) matrix for $n$-dimension. (I don't know what this matrix would be called in general; I'm sure it is used often.) This is used as a smoothing prior on a function sampled on a uniform grid. For a $1$-dimensional function, the matrix is

$$C = \rho \begin{bmatrix}
  1  & \alpha & \alpha^2 & \cdots & \alpha^n \\\\
  \alpha    &    1             & \alpha    & \cdots  & \alpha^{n-1}\\\\
  \alpha^2 & \alpha   &    1    &     \\\\
\vdots  & \vdots & & \ddots & \\\\
\alpha^n & \alpha^{n-1} & & & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

and I know the inverse, which is

$$C^{-1} = \frac{1}{\rho(1-\alpha^2)} \begin{bmatrix}
  1            &    -\alpha     &  & & 0\\\\
  -\alpha    &    1+\alpha^2             & - \alpha     \\\\
   & -\alpha   &    1+\alpha^2  &\ddots       \\\\
  & &\ddots  & \ddots & -\alpha \\\\
0 & & & -\alpha & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

(This can be also found in Kac, M., Murdock, W., and Szegö, G. (1953). On the eigenvalues of certain Hermitian forms. J. Rational Mech. Anal, 2:767–800.)

I would imagine that this can be generalized to higher dimensional case where the $\alpha$ now spreads in each direction. This would allow my uniformly sampled $n$-dimensional function to be smooth. Sort of having the form

\begin{equation}
C_{(i,j),(k,l)} = \rho \alpha_x^{|i-k|} \alpha_y^{|j-l|},
\end{equation}

but as a giant matrix for flattened function (the vec operation; representing the $n$-dimensional function as a vector with some ordering). Can anybody recommend a book on such symbolic matrix inversions that would have this?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, this is not normal: editing a 7 years old post, inactive, only to perform minor changes! Do you realize that this bumps it to the main page, for nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $C_{(i,j)(k,l)}$ is the Kronecker product of two $C$ matrices (with different constant $\alpha_x$ and $\alpha_y$. And $(A \otimes B)^{-1}=A^{-1}\otimes B^{-1}$.

Comment: If $C_{(i,j),(k,l)}=\rho \alpha_x^{∣i−j∣} \alpha_x^{∣k−l∣}$, then I would agree, but the indices are a bit mixed. Does it still hold?

Comment: I think so, unless I'm totally misunderstanding your notation. The pair $(i,j)$ forms the row index of the large matrix, doesn't it?

Comment: Correct. Well, $(i,j)$ for column, $(k,l)$ for row, but that's not important. The Kronecker product of $C_{i,k}$ and $C_{j,l}$ is correct. Thanks.